# PDFSharp blank pages

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

Tried to open a pdf result in blank pages. Retry with same pdf displayed all pages with content.
It happen only once & couldn't reproduce it.

My application work with 3 steps.

1. Open PDF
2. Add Barcode Image
3. Save PDF

Source pdf had 2 pages with text content, output pdf had only stamped pdf without content.
I believe something went wrong in following line because number of pages are correct but blank.

```
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
```

I need find reason of failure but don't have any idea what went wrong at first time. I have already gone through following questions but they have different case.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52453789/9102192
- [PDFSharp returning blank pages when adding password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727529/pdfsharp-returning-blank-pages-when-adding-password)

Can anyone help me finding root cause for this incident or any guesses ?

Comment: which framework is your application running on: .Net framework or .Net core?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.2 & PdfSharp 1.32.3057.0

Comment: With version 1.32 you are missing the bug fixes made in 5 years. I don't know what happened on your computer, so I can't promise it won't happen again with version 1.50. Maybe interference with another app, an update, or another unusual circumstance.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow,  Where can I check bugfixes for PdfSharp ?

Comment: Give us a link to your pdf and we may find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do something like this:

```
using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = PdfReader.Open("source", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify)){ 

 // Logic to insert image into pdf // 

pdfDoc.Save("targetPath")
}
```

Comment: Its nice approach but I don't see how it can solve pdf failure that is happening only once.

Comment: It is hard to solve an error that only happens once, especially if you didn't store the error code :/

Comment: Actually It didn't throw any exception instead just white pdf. Is their any way to get internal logs to debug  ?

Comment: I had this issue a while ago, which was happening because I had the wrong version of PdfSharp installed, it was not compatible with the framework I was using...